# how to sync the AD Group in your central administrator in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to to give rights to a webpart using Target Audiance in Sharepoint 2013 But when i click Global Audience  and click on Search it says No audience was found based on your search request. Refine your search text.

Than I select Distribution/User group is says :   No security groups or distribution lists were found based on your search request. Refine the search text, and then rerun the search request.

Than I tried Last option Sharepoint User Group it says:No audience was found based on your search request. Refine your search text.

So I came to know I need Syncronize  The Active Directory Group In Central Admin.And I checked that in Central admin --->Manage Service Application-->

And what i say there that User Profile Service Application  is saying started
 and User Profile Service Application  is started.Now how to get my SharePoint user group in that Target audience so that I can give rights to webpart in sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

User profile synchronization doesn't have anything to do with this. It is only used to synchronize properties of user profile objects in the AD with the user profile database in SharePoint. Group membership is a property of groups, not used.

If your AD group is a 'distribution' group, rather than a security group, you won't be able to use it to assign permissions (and I'm pretty sure that applies to audience targeting as well). Distribution groups don't have Security Identifiers (SIDs), which are used under the hood for granting access. Do other AD groups show up in your searches?

Comment: No not any other groups show their when use target audience.But when I click on site settings and look for people and groups i am able  to see all the usergroups.